# recursive algorithm for file structure for a single type of file

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I would like an algorithm which generates a file structure starting from a user specified directory, but have it only show a specific type of file (.resx). So far I have the code below, which shows the file structure and displays only .resx files, but the problem is that it shows all of the directories which do not contain a .resx file as well. i.e. if a treeviewitem or any of its children does not contain a .resx file, it should not be there.

```
void DirSearch(string sDir, TreeViewItem parentItem)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
            {
                TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
                item.Header = d;
                parentItem.Items.Add(item);
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.resx"))
                    {
                        TreeViewItem subitem = new TreeViewItem();
                        subitem.Header = f;
                        subitem.Tag = f;
                        item.Items.Add(subitem);
                    }
                DirSearch(d, item);
            }

        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the TreeViewItem representing a directory to its parent **only** if it has children (*.resx files, or sub-directories containing *.resx files). Note that DirSearch is called recursively before that check is being made.

```
    void DirSearch(string sDir, TreeViewItem parentItem)
    {
        ......

        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
            TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
            item.Header = d;
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.resx"))
            {
                TreeViewItem subitem = new TreeViewItem();
                subitem.Header = f;
                subitem.Tag = f;
                item.Items.Add(subitem);
            }
            DirSearch(d, item);

            if (item.Items.Count > 0)
                parentItem.Items.Add(item);
        }

        ......
    }
```

Comment: @elgonzo- Perfect! Thank you. I have nightmares about recursion, hate when I have to use it.

Comment: @user1003131, don't worry, these nightmares will fade eventually. I tell from experience... ;)